# how to disable key temporarily on command when another key is pressed

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, gaming

Im playing this game and I frequently use arrows but theres a sort of boost when the arrows aren't pressed while im pressing D, the game is extremely based off timing and coordination( I have the timing but the coordination as in releasing a arrow before pressing D is my problem ) I just want a script to ahk, or another program that can disable arrows while I press D.

Comment: Won't this be cheating to play a game using script support? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that checks whether <kbd>D</kbd> is pressed whenever you press one of the arrow keys.  Give it a try.

```
Up::
Down::
Left::
Right::
    If ! GetKeystate("D", "P")
        Send {%A_ThisHotkey%}
    Else
        Return
```